# MySql subqueries and max or group by?

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
ID STUDENT CLASS QUESTION ANSWER   TIME
 1   1      1       1       c     12:30
 2   1      1       1       d     12:36
 3   1      1       2       a     12:38
 4   2      1       1       b     11:24
 5   2      1       1       c     11:26
 6   2      1       3       d     11:35
 7   2      3       3       b     11:24
```

I'm trying to write a query that does this:

*For each STUDENT in a specific CLASS select the most recent ANSWER for each QUESTION.*

So, choosing class "1" would return:

```
ID STUDENT CLASS QUESTION ANSWER   TIME
 2   1      1       1       d     12:36
 3   1      1       2       a     12:38
 5   2      1       1       c     11:26
 6   2      1       3       d     11:35
```

I've tried various combinations of subqueries, joins, and grouping, but nothing is working. Any ideas?

Comment: it'll be a subquery. subquery pulls out a `id, max(time)` grouped by student, then you do a join against that subquery to fetch the rest of the data in the row that has that id.

Comment: Can you please show which queries have you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a sub-query to get most recent `ANSWER` per `QUESTION`, Then use this as a derived table and join back to the original table:

```
 SELECT m.*
 FROM mytable AS m
 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT STUDENT,  QUESTION, MAX(`TIME`) AS mTime
    FROM mytable
    WHERE CLASS = 1
    GROUP BY STUDENT, QUESTION 
) AS d ON m.STUDENT = d.STUDENT AND m.QUESTION = d.QUESTION AND m.`TIME` = d.mTime
WHERE m.CLASS = 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/945f0/1)

Comment: I was missing the grouping and joining by multiple columns. This worked - thanks so much!