# How to further filter GROUP BY record in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

Please check the images i want complete ROW of query-id "43"(and with another nic_id max query_id row) but it give me only max query_id, I tried different queries for-example:

```
SELECT `Query_id`, `nic_id`, `date`, `subject`, `followup_no`, MAX(Query_id) as queryid FROM `sales_queries` GROUP BY `nic_id` HAVING MAX(`Query_id`)

SELECT `Query_id`, `nic_id`, `date`, `subject`, `followup_no`, MAX(Query_id) as queryid FROM `sales_queries` WHERE  GROUP BY `nic_id` HAVING MAX(`Query_id`)

SELECT  `Query_id`, `nic_id`, `date`, `subject`, `followup_no`, MAX(Query_id) as mxqueryid    FROM `sales_queries`WHERE `Query_id` = (SELECT MAX(`Query_id`) FROM `sales_queries`) GROUP BY `nic_id`
```

when customer visit again followup increase(+1) with his same nic_id with different subject.
[image: only one customer data in table]

i want complete 43 row with subject "Registration4", date etc

NOT THIS, it should be Registration4 date:2015-09-11
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31597492/mysql-subqueries-and-max-or-group-by), you can use a subquery and join in order to fetch the results you are after. Something similar to the following should work:

```
SELECT `Query_id`, `nic_id`, `date`, `subject`, `followup_no`
FROM `sales_queries` AS sq
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(`Query_id`) AS mId
    FROM `sales_queries`
    GROUP BY `nic_id`
) AS subsq ON subsq.mId = sq.Query_id
```

Comment: Sir please check below answer of mine and Kindly help me out how to do it. I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: I'd suggest you ask this in a new question, linking to it in this previous question, and and linking back from your new question. Also expand what you are looking for as I can't tell from your description below what extra info you need; what results are you getting? What results do you want? Your original question above was very good in this regard as you provided screenshots.

Comment: As  you asked me, i asked another question and waiting for  you kind response. Many Thanks

Comment: Dear Benjamin waiting for your response.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32695088/how-to-solve-mysql-complex-query

Comment: Dear Benjamin still waiting for your response :(

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32695088/how-to-solve-mysql-complex-query

Comment: Dear Benjamin, please check below video, i am using same query but with 3 different date ranges. screencast-o-matic.com/watch/co66lsfWuf

Answer (score 0):

i am using below three queries in three different pages. I want IF MAX(`Query_id`) is not available specific range of dates then it ignore it.

```
/////////////   QUERY 1  \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
```

$sql="SELECT * FROM `sales_queries`  AS sq 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX(`Query_id`) AS mId FROM `sales_queries` WHERE  `follow_up` > '".$s_date."'  GROUP BY `nic_id` ) AS subsq 
ON subsq.mId = sq.Query_id";

/////////////   QUERY 2  \\\\\\\\\\\

$sql="SELECT * FROM `sales_queries`  AS sq 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX(`Query_id`) AS mId FROM `sales_queries`  WHERE  `follow_up` BETWEEN '".$s_date."' AND '".$e_date."' GROUP BY `nic_id` ) AS subsq 
ON subsq.mId = sq.Query_id";

/////////////   QUERY 3  \\\\\\\\\\\

$sql="SELECT * FROM `sales_queries`  AS sq 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX(`Query_id`) AS mId FROM `sales_queries`  WHERE `follow_up` BETWEEN '".$s_date."' AND '".$e_date."' GROUP BY `nic_id` ) AS subsq 
ON subsq.mId = sq.Query_id";