# how to solve mysql Complex QUERY?

Tags: php, mysql

Reference to my previous question.

[How to further filter GROUP BY record in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517231/how-to-further-filter-group-by-record-in-mysql/32693981#32693981)
There are three different pages where i will use same query but with different dates as shown below:
In week_fallowup.php date range is

s_date= 21/Sept/2015

e_date= 28/Sept/2015

In fornight_fallowup.php date range is

s_date= 29/Sept/2015

e_date= 13/Oct/2015

In month_fallowup.php date range is

s_date= 14/Sept/2015

There are three followup pages Week_followup.php, Fornight_followup.php & Month_followup.php in that i am using below three queries:

```
/////////////   QUERY for week_followup.php  \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
$sql="SELECT * FROM sales_queries AS sq INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX(Query_id) AS mId FROM sales_queries WHERE follow_up BETWEEN '".$s_date."' AND '".$e_date."' GROUP BY nic_id ) AS subsq ON subsq.mId = sq.Query_id";

///////////// QUERY for fornight_followup.php \\\\\\
$sql="SELECT * FROM sales_queries AS sq INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX(Query_id) AS mId FROM sales_queries WHERE follow_up BETWEEN '".$s_date."' AND '".$e_date."' GROUP BY nic_id ) AS subsq ON subsq.mId = sq.Query_id";

///////////// QUERY for month_followup.php \\\\\\
$sql="SELECT * FROM sales_queries AS sq INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX(Query_id) AS mId FROM sales_queries WHERE follow_up > '".$s_date."' GROUP BY nic_id ) AS subsq ON subsq.mId = sq.Query_id";
```

It works perfectly but when someone fallow query on month page and give date of fallowup in next week, it shows on both pages week and month 
what i want is, it show only one  MAX(Query_id) either it is in week_followup.php, fornight_followup.php or month_followup.php. ONLY MAX(query_id)

Comment: if someone need further details please let me know, sorry for bad english

Comment: Seems like week_followup query and fornight_followup are identical. Besides that, hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: show some sample data and what you want achieve means output data you required.

Comment: Forexample
In week_fallowup.php date range is
$s_date= 21/Sept/2015 
$e_date= 28/Sept/2015

In fornight_fallowup.php date range is
$s_date= 29/Sept/2015 
$e_date= 13/Oct/2015

In month_fallowup.php date range is
$s_date= 14/Sept/2015

Comment: This appears not to be a SQL issue but an issue with the PHP code - as previously asked, it would be best to provide examples of: 1. Input data (as in the DB, not parameters to the queries above) 2. Expected output data 3. Actual output data. Without either example PHP code, or all of the data above (and preferably both) it is beyond our power to help.

Comment: Dear Benjamin, please check below video, i am using same query but with 3 different date ranges.

http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/co66lsfWuf

Answer (score 0):

Forexample
In week_fallowup.php date range is

s_date= 21/Sept/2015

e_date= 28/Sept/2015

In fornight_fallowup.php date range is

s_date= 29/Sept/2015

e_date= 13/Oct/2015

In month_fallowup.php date range is

s_date= 14/Sept/2015